# How to convert custom Pytorch model to torchscript (pth to pt model)?

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I trained a custom model with PyTorch using colab environment. I successfully saved the trained model to Google Drive with the name `model_final.pth`. I want to convert `model_final.pth` to `model_final.pt` so that it can be used on mobile devices.

The code I use to train the model is as follows:

```
from detectron2.engine import DefaultTrainer

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml"))
cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN = ("mouse_train",)
cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ()
cfg.DATALOADER.NUM_WORKERS = 2
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = model_zoo.get_checkpoint_url("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml") 
cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH = 2
cfg.SOLVER.BASE_LR = 0.00025 
cfg.SOLVER.MAX_ITER = 1000   
cfg.SOLVER.STEPS = []        
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE = 512   
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 1  
cfg.OUTPUT_DIR="drive/Detectron2/"

os.makedirs(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, exist_ok=True)
trainer = DefaultTrainer(cfg) 
trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
trainer.train()
```

The code I used to convert the model is as follows:

```
from detectron2.modeling import build_model
import torch
import torchvision

print("cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS: ",cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS)   ## RETURNS : cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS:  drive/Detectron2/model_final.pth
model = build_model(cfg)
model.eval()
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
traced_script_module.save("drive/Detectron2/model-final.pt")
```

But I am getting this error **IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 3** :

```
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS:  drive/Detectron2/model_final.pth
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py:593: RuntimeWarning: Iterating over a tensor might cause the trace to be incorrect. Passing a tensor of different shape won't change the number of iterations executed (and might lead to errors or silently give incorrect results).
  'incorrect results).', category=RuntimeWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-8e544c0f39c8> in <module>()
      7 model.eval()
      8 example = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)
----> 9 traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
     10 traced_script_module.save("drive/Detectron2/model_final.pt")

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/detectron2/modeling/meta_arch/rcnn.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    219         Normalize, pad and batch the input images.
    220         """
--> 221         images = [x["image"].to(self.device) for x in batched_inputs]
    222         images = [(x - self.pixel_mean) / self.pixel_std for x in images]
    223         images = ImageList.from_tensors(images, self.backbone.size_divisibility)

IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Detectron2 models expect a dictionary or a list of dictionaries as input](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/models.html#model-input-format)  by default.

So you can not directly use `torch.jit.trace` function. But they provide a wrapper, called [TracingAdapter](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/detectron2/export/flatten.py#L185), that allows models to take a tensor or a tuple of tensors as input. You can find out how to use it in their [torchscript tests](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/tests/test_export_torchscript.py#L89).

The code for tracing your Mask RCNN model could be (I did not try it):

```
import torch
import torchvision
from detectron2.export.flatten import TracingAdapter

def inference_func(model, image):
    inputs = [{"image": image}]
    return model.inference(inputs, do_postprocess=False)[0]

print("cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS: ",cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS)   ## RETURNS : cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS:  drive/Detectron2/model_final.pth
model = build_model(cfg)
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)
wrapper = TracingAdapter(model, example, inference_func)
wrapper.eval()
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(wrapper, (example,))
traced_script_module.save("drive/Detectron2/model-final.pt")
```

More info on detectron2 deployment with tracing can be found [here](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/deployment.html#deployment-with-tracing-or-scripting).

Answer (score 2):

This example can help. This is approach like bottom method. But it with  .pth   using obviously.

```
import torch
import torchvision
from unet import UNet 

model = UNet(3, 2)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("best_weights.pth"))
model.eval()
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 320, 480)
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
traced_script_module.save("model.pt")
```

Code from [this](https://www.programmersought.com/article/67338331443/) site.